# select term from reference field but deny edit term

Tags: taxonomy-terms

How can I allow users of a particular role select a term from a reference field on a node but deny them to 'edit' the terms from that reference field?

Selecting terms: great. 
If, under taxonomy permissions, you tick 'Administer vocabularies and terms' for a particular role, they will see my own created term reference field and they are able to select the term of their preference which is great.

Editing terms: bad.
But if they view the node and see the term, they can click on that term and then they also have the 'edit' permission to edit the term. Surely not what we want because the user might potentially mess up the settings of my carefully designed term reference field.

I'm using taxonomy access control but that only takes care of the node access, not of the term edit access.

Comment: What's the point actually to have a term reference field if the user who needs to select (tick the box) the preferred referenced term can also change that term into whatever they like? And how do we prevent them from editing that term?

Comment: I think I'm going to need to create a module for that. What do you think? But I'm not sure what code to use in my module. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It appears to be a bug in both the rc version and the dev version of the module [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) for D7. Details from project page:

> Access control for user roles based on taxonomy categories (vocabulary, terms).
>
> - Automatically controls access to nodes (based on their taxonomy terms).
> - Configuration page for each user role.
> - Three node access permission types: View, Update, Delete.
> - Two term access types: View tag, Add tag.

Once a user has access to the edit node form AND they are allowed to 'add tag' on the access-rules-for-user page for that vocabulary, that term will show up and will be able to be ticked/set on the node form regardless of whether or not the default and other vocabulary terms in that vocabulary have been set to 'allow' or 'deny' the 'add tag' on the access-rules-for-user page. Hopefully this makes sense to others as well.